# How to extract only 6 digit number from a random String message? 6 digit number is not in the beginning or end of the message

Tags: java, android

I have a String message with 6 digit OTP. but it is not in the beginning or in the end. So indexing couldn't help. and replace is working but my message may changed any time so this trick also failed. 
My message example :

> Your OTP code is : 123456
>
> FA+9qCX9VSu

```
String subFirst= message.replace("<#> Your OTP code is : ", "");
String finalOTP = message.replace("FA+9qCX9VSu", "");
```

it produce the expected result for only this static message.
How to get only 6 digit number for any message. or is there any other way to extract OTP from message ?

Comment: in your example is FA+9qCX9VSu OTP and 123456 is the extracted code ?

Comment: No, FA+9qCX9VSu is hash key and 123456 is OTP. I want extract only 123456.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract any 6 digit number from any `String` message. 
"|" is used to lookup more possible combinations. Only "\d{6}" also give you the correct result for your problem.

```
//find any 6 digit number
Pattern mPattern = Pattern.compile("(|^)\\d{6}");

if(message!=null) {
    Matcher mMatcher = mPattern.matcher(message);
    if(mMatcher.find()) {
        String otp = mMatcher.group(0);
        Log.i(TAG,"Final OTP: "+ otp);
    }else {
        //something went wrong
        Log.e(TAG,"Failed to extract the OTP!! ");
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for this answer!! Thanks :) .

Answer (score 1):

you can get otp like this.

```
String allNum=message.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
String otp=allNum.substring(0,6);
```

Comment: did not worked!! got result : 12345699. expected 123456

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex to find the number substring and the just take the 6 first from the substring, you can find how to use regex here : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: This is not an answer since it only points to regular expressions in general. Post this as a comment or improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

if your message is always start with "Your OTP code is : " and have break line (\n)
after codes use this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("is : (.*?)\\n", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
    while (matcher.find()) {
      Log.i("tag" , matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: I have a solution for static message added with my question. problem is message can different for different user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope this will help you.

```
String expression = "[0-9]{6}";
    CharSequence inputStr = message;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
msg = 'Your OTP code is : 123456'
otp = msg.split()[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex like this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    String input = "Your OTP code is : 123456\r\n" + "\r\n" + "FA+9qCX9VSu";
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(":\\s([0-9]{6})");
    Matcher m = regex.matcher(input);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String message="The OTP is 145673 and the same is active for next 20 mins";
System.out.println(message.replaceFirst("\d{6}", "******"));

I hope this helps.